# ParseException when using DecimalFormat

Tags: android, kotlin

I am fetching the device storage space size using the following code.

```
val space: String = Formatter.formatFileSize(
    context,
    StatFs(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()).availableBytes
)
```

I am using a formatter to format commas.

```
val format = DecimalFormat("#.##", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ROOT))
```

Then I am doing parsing like below. The unit value is replaced with an empty string.

```
format.parse(space.replace("GB", "", ignoreCase = true).trim()).toDouble()
```

This is raising exception to few users.

```
Caused by java.text.ParseException
Unparseable number: "‏‪49.71 ‬‏"
```

EDIT: The number coming over here is RTL value. How can I parse such a value using decimal format?

Comment: There is whitespace in string. Check does `trim()` really trim it. Try to use `replace()` instead of trim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the regex to solve this issue.

```
val bidiFormatter = BidiFormatter.getInstance()
if (bidiFormatter.isRtl(space)) { //If in the case of RTL
    space = space.replace(" \u202C\u200F", "")
    val regex = "([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(space)

    while (matcher.find()) {
        try {
             availableSpace = format.parse(matcher.group()).toDouble()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }
} else {
     try { //LTR. Parsing is required to handle european languages
          availableSpace = format.parse(space).toDouble()
     } catch (e: Exception) {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong either with the String you are providing to the parse() method. It seems there is a **zero-width null character bug** in your String. That is your string has a Unicode u+FEFF Byte order mark character at the beginning and end of the string, which is known as a “Zero-width null character”. It's not whitespace, so trim() will not remove it.
For validation just print the length of your String and observing that it would be 2 longer than expected.

**How to resolve:** Trim these characters. You can write a function to trim before parse it, something like below:

```
fun String.fullTrim() = trim().replace("\uFEFF", "")
val deviceSpace = space.replace("GB", "", ignoreCase = true) 
val result = deviceSpace.fullTrim().toDouble()
```

Comment: Please check the EDIT portion.

Comment: Your decimal format seems OK but the value you getting from RTL seems suspicious. So I think that needs to be take care.

Comment: This is specific to device settings I guess. Not all users are having this issue. Might be some locale issue. But not getting a solution for the same.

Comment: @Anju, In case of locale issue, then you can also try first converting to NumberFormat before Casting it to DecimalFormat something like below:
val nFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ROOT);
val dFormat = (DecimalFormat) nFormat;
dFormat.applyPattern("#.##");